# Change textView.text when a specific image is displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this interactive game with 2 buttons and 1 image where images are stored in a map of drawables. The current image is `var currentImageDrawable`, so when you click a button, the image changes together with the `currentImageVariable`. But since I added a `TextView`, just to change the text when a specific image is displayed, unfortunately it doesn't change. It just remains at the first text which is "Start the game?".

```
    import com.example.thegame.R.drawable.*

    var tv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    var currentImageDrawable = menu
    data class Choice(val choice1: Int, val choice2: Int)

    val choicesMap = mapOf(
            menu to Choice(door1, menu),
            door1 to Choice(door_inside, door_back),
            door_inside to Choice(door_inside2, door_inside2_1),
            door_back to Choice(door_back2, door_back2_1)

        )


    buttonYes.setOnClickListener {
        currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable]!!.choice1
        imageView.setImageResource(currentImageDrawable)
    }
    buttonNo.setOnClickListener {
        currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable]!!.choice2
        imageView.setImageResource(currentImageDrawable)
        if (currentImageDrawable== menu) {
            finishAffinity()
        }
    }

    if (currentImageDrawable== menu) {
        tv.setText("Start the game?") }
    else if (currentImageDrawable== door1) {
        tv.setText("Open the door?") }
    else {
        tv.setText("")
    }

    /*
    when (currentImageDrawable) {
        menu -> tv.setText("start the game?")
        door1 -> tv.setText("open the door?")
        else -> tv.text = ("")
    }
    */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code comes from your OnCreate method, can it be?
OnCreate is executed once when you create your activity. To change the text content when clicking the button you have to write the part in the OnClickListener.

```
buttonYes.setOnClickListener {
    currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable]!!.choice1
    imageView.setImageResource(currentImageDrawable)
    if (currentImageDrawable== menu) {
        tv.setText("Start the game?") }
    else if (currentImageDrawable== door1) {
        tv.setText("Open the door?") }
    else {
        tv.setText("")
    }
}

buttonNo.setOnClickListener {
    currentImageDrawable = choicesMap[currentImageDrawable]!!.choice2
    imageView.setImageResource(currentImageDrawable)
    if (currentImageDrawable== menu) {
        tv.setText("Start the game?")
        finishAffinity()
    } else if (currentImageDrawable== door1) {
        tv.setText("Open the door?") 
    } else {
        tv.setText("")
    }
}
```

The OnClick method is not executed immediately, but each time the button is clicked.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Feel free to mark this question as accepted answer so that other people can see it's solved.